# Drawbacks of using singleton with models

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

So let's say I'm making a React Redux app for handling a library. I want to create an API for my backend where each model (book, author, etc) is displayed in the UI.
Each model does not provide a public constructor, but a from static function which ensures that only one instance per id exists:

```
static from (id: string) {
  if (Books.books[id]) {
    return Books.books[id];
  }
  return Book.books[id] = new Book(id);
}
```

Each model provides an async fetch function which will fetch its props using the backend. The advantage is that there is no thousands instances, also I don't have to fetch twice (if two parts of my app needs the same model, fetch will actually be called only once). But I fail to find any drawbacks, except that there might be a discrepancy between a code that fetches its models and one that assumes they are still not fetched, but I still don't see when it would really be an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I fail to find any drawbacks

I see at least two :

- The singleton pattern is an anti pattern.
  Static factory methods don't provide explicit dependencies.
  Mocking the method in unit tests or switch to another implementation will be harder.
- You don't have cache size limitation.
  For short lists, it is OK.
  But if you may cache many objects, you should keep only last recently used instances.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two problems:

- Are your models mutable? If you change a property of the instance, it would reflect everywhere that instance is used. That might either be desirable, or not at all. And with that `from` method, you cannot do anything about it.
  If your models are immutable, sharing instances is in fact a common practice, also known as [hash consing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing).
- Your implementation leaks memory like hell. The instances will stay referenced from that `books` array/object even if they are no longer needed.

Comment: Well the models should sometimes provide a function could modify one of its props if it's what you mean. I liked this way because every model holder would then use the up-to-date object, and also it could provide a simple API to listen for changes (and then change the state of my components eventually updating the view).

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Everything being up-to-date is nice, except when you don't want it. And you cannot control whether to use this feature or not - the `from` function decides it. Also the models would simply change at any arbitrary time, there is no observable interface or so where you could explicitly listen for updates.